# $wpdb->results method without any result printed or error

Tags: mysql, wordpress

with the code below, Why it doesn't show any result? What could be the problem?
Thanks for any suggest

```
function vendorDatails( $param)
{
global $wpdb;

$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT vendor_id FROM {$wpdb->lqrhxf_pv_commission} WHERE order_id = '%d'", $param);

$result = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );

        foreach ($result as $row)
            {
                echo $row->vendor_id;
            }

        echo $result[0]->vendor_id;

//clean all results
$wpdb->flush();
```

}

Comment: Are you sure `lqrhxf_` is not your table prefix? Also id of `order_id` should not be wrap in quotes `''`

Answer (score 0):

Try following changed query

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT vendor_id FROM $wpdb->lqrhxf_pv_commission WHERE order_id = %d", $param);
```